# Questions about turning the HTML code that uses Cytoscape.js into a web link accessible by other people

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, cytoscape.js

I am able to use the Cytoscape.js library to display a network graph on my own web browser. I wrote a HTML file containing the JavaScript code that takes in the graph JSON and style JSON files from my laptop and calls cytoscape(). When I run my HTML code on my laptop, the network graph is displayed on my own web browser and I can play with the graph.

Now I need to run the HTML code on our Linux server and then send a web link to the user, so that the user can click on that web link to view the displayed network graph on their own web browser, and the user should also be able to move nodes & edges around just as I did on my own web browser.

I am not a web developer so I am missing some very basic knowledge. I think I probably need to link the HTML code to a web domain (deploying the HTML code on a hosting server with domain name). I was just wondering if you could offer me some advice on how to do this?

Another question (which is more important) is: Assume I am able to link the HTML code to a web domain. When the user clicks on the web link to view the displayed network graph on their own web browser, is the user still able to move nodes & edges around?

The graph JSON and style JSON files and some additional JavaScript code the HTML loads in reside on our server. I am not sure if there are any issues about this when the user accesses the web link?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad.  You'd be best off searching for some books to read regarding web dev.

You might find using [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) a bit easier than managing your own server, but you really should do some reading either way.

Basic resources to get started

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Introduction_to_Web_development
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!